# Intermittent batch read failure from Aerospike

Tags: nosql, real-time, scale, high-availability, aerospike

We have frequent batch read failure from aerospike batch read. With 86k qps request on aerospike cluster with 12 machines and 12 replication factor, when we do batch read for 9 content (in single request) sometimes we get only 8 content. I guess it is due to rebalancing of the cluster. We tried max_retries = 2, it doesn't help much although. What can be possible solution for it to make batch read fully consistent?

```
Aerospike Query Client
Version 3.16.0
C Client Version 4.3.20
```

Comment: What server version are you using?

Comment: Could you add the code snippet to your question?

Comment: Specifically, are you using `BatchPolicy.useBatchDirect = true`? This tell the batch system to use the older method with didn't support proxy.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are running into an issue with a the batch system in a much older version of Aerospike. Older versions couldn't proxy individual reads when the record was moved to another server. This changes at some point in the 3.x lineage.

Could you provide the Aerospike Server version that you are using?

Comment: Looks like the client you use (4.3.20) would force you to use the batch-index which should proxy (https://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/c/usage/incompatible.html#-version-4-3-20-remove-as_policy_batch-use_batch_direct-). So this is not expected and rebalancing of the cluster or migrations shouldn't cause records to be missed. Having said that, I do know that there are quite a lot of improvements on batch retries in more recent client versions, so I would encourage upgrading both client and server if you want to rely on retries for batch.